# Qt5.2 cannot show the viewfinder on android screen

Tags: android, qt

Qt is new to me.
I followed their example Camera Example and QML Camera Example to build my own app. I am using pure C++ language instead of QML. The app is able to show the viewfinder on screen in Desktop version but unable in Android. Everything(OSX, NDK, Android SDK, QT) is in latest version

widget.h

```
#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H

#include <QVideoWidget>
#include <QCamera>
#include <QCameraViewfinder>

namespace Ui {
  class Widget;
}

class Widget : public QVideoWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

  public:
    explicit Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Widget();

  private:
    Ui::Widget *ui;
    QCamera *camera;
};

#endif // WIDGET_H
```

widget.cpp

```
#include "widget.h"
#include "ui_widget.h"

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
  QVideoWidget(parent),
  ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
  ui->setupUi(this);

  camera = new QCamera(this);
  camera->setCaptureMode(QCamera::CaptureStillImage);
  camera->setViewfinder(this);
  camera->start();
}

Widget::~Widget()
{
  delete ui;
}
```

my.pro

```
QT       += core gui widgets multimedia multimediawidgets

TARGET = opencv
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        widget.cpp

HEADERS  += widget.h

FORMS    += widget.ui

CONFIG += mobility console
MOBILITY =
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by not able to show? Do you get a blank screen?

Comment: just white screen in android

Comment: It is stated in the comments of [this](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-38233) bug report that currently only the QML version is supported and that support to widgets will be (possibly) added in a future release.